# TFS Windows Explorer Integration - Getting version history outside of VS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, explorer, windows-explorer, tfvc

I worked for year using CVS source control with Windows Explorer integration using TortoiseCVS which enabled me to view the history of my files in a graphical way and allow me to compare any 2 versions of the file without the need to open IDEs.

Lately I started working in a new place that uses TFS which require me to open Visual Studio every time I want to see the file history.

It would be great to have this level of integration between TFS and Windows Explorer. I wonder if any third party has developed such functionality?
Currently I use C# with Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

This is what I see when I choose Revision Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell integration can be installed as part of the [Visual Studio Power Tools for Team Foundation Server 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f). Make sure you check the "Windows Shell Extensions" option.

[image]

To see the revision graph, I am afraid you still need to open Visual Studio and use the Track Changeset feature which seems the closest as far as I can tell.

[image]

That and the "Incoming Changes" codelens that was added to Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and which is going to be part of Visual Studio 2015 Professional and up.

[image]

Comment: + Thanks a lot Jesse for your quick reply and I appreciate your help. Currently the TFS server is at version 2012, but I use VS 2013, does that make any difference?

Comment: For the Windows Explorer integration you must use that matches the latest Visual Studio version on your system that the Power tools are available for.